# show an array inside of an array in a csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I have created an array using

```
    $processed[$y] = array('source' => $source,
            'check total' => number_format($checkTotal, 2, '.', ''),//($rows['total'], 2, '.', ''),
            'check number' => $num,
            'table' => $invTable,
            'skus' => $skuArray,
            'check amount' => number_format($amount, 2, '.', '')
            );
$y++;
```

My $skuArray is an array that contains all of the sku's that are associated with a specific check number.  I am attempting to have it displayed like:

```
    source  check total check number  table        skus     check amount
    MNC       152.32       649       inv_temp    10198547   152.32
                                                 10195874
```

so it will list all of the sku's attached to a specific check nuimber before it lists the next item.
Here is my function to convert $processed to a csv file:

```
    function to_csv( $array ) {
 $csv = "";

 if (count($array) == 0) return "No Processed checks found";

 ## Grab the first element to build the header
 $arr = array_pop( $array );
 $temp = array();
 foreach( $arr as $key => $data ) {
   $temp[] = $key;
 }
 $csv = implode( ',', $temp ) . "\r\n";

 ## Add the data from the first element
 $csv .= to_csv_line( $arr );

 ## Add the data for the rest
 foreach( $array as $arr ) {
   $csv .= to_csv_line( $arr );
 }

 return $csv;
    }

    function to_csv_line( $array ) {
 $temp = array();
 foreach( $array as $elt ) {
   $temp[] = '"' . addslashes( $elt ) . '"';
 }

 $string = implode( ',', $temp ) . "\r\n";

 return $string;
    }
```

How can I accomplish this?  I have tried using array('skus=>$skuArray), but it just gave me "Array" in the results.

UPDATE: Here is what the array looks like when I do a var_dump($skuArray)
array(1075) { [0]=> string(8) "10182997" [1]=> string(8) "10190313" [2]=> string(8) "10190314" [3]=> string(8) "10190315" etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've provided a solution that is untested, so use at your own discretion.

I've done my best to explain everything through comments in the code.

1. Remove the first sku value from the sku array, assign it to the first line.
2. Add additional skus to a temporary array based on the line keys.
3. Check for temporary sku array, and create the additional lines from it.

Your final `to_csv` function will look something like this:

```
function to_csv( $array ) {
    $csv = "";

    if (count($array) == 0) return "No Processed checks found";

    ## Grab the first element to build the header
    $arr = $array[0];
    $temp = array();
    foreach( $arr as $key => $data ) {
        $temp[] = $key;
    }
    $csv = implode( ',', $temp ) . "\r\n";

    ## Process each line
    foreach( $array as $arr ) {

        ## Check for multiple sku values.  Create a temporary array for them to add them after this line.
        if(isset($arr['skus']) && is_array($arr['skus']))
        {
            //Remove the first value (since we only need it for the actual line item)
            $sku_value = $arr['skus'][0];
            unset($arr['skus'][0]);

            //Create temporary lines for each sku
            $temp_sku_arrays = array();
            foreach($arr['skus'] as $sku)
            {
                $sku_array = array();
                foreach($arr as $key => $value)
                {
                    //Set only the sku key with a value.
                    $sku_array[$key] = ($key == 'skus' ? $sku : '');
                }
                $temp_sku_arrays[] = $sku_array;
            }

            //Set the first line to the first sku value.
            $arr['skus'] = $sku_value;          
        }  

        $csv .= to_csv_line( $arr );

        //Check for additional sku lines, then add them
        if(isset($temp_sku_arrays) && is_array($temp_sku_arrays))
        {
            foreach($temp_sku_arrays as $sku_array)
            {   
                $csv .= to_csv_line( $sku_array );
            }
            unset($temp_sku_arrays);
        }
    }

    return $csv;
}
```

Comment: thanks Axel, I tried what you have, and it is only returning the sku array for the last item in the $processed[$y] array 9 so it is the first item listed in the csv file.  Any idea on how to fix this?  thanks again for the help.

Comment: Correction, the sku is for the first item in the list, not the last.

Comment: Are there any additional lines added after the first line (blanks?).

Comment: just has "Array" where the sku should be.

Comment: Please be more descriptive.  1 line with `Array` in the row (no blank lines after?)

Comment: Here is what it looks like:Processed: 
source,check total,check number,table,skus,check amount 
"","0.00","463","Check not found","10182997","28.25" 
"FRAM","18.00","1873","checks table","Array","18.00" 
"","0.00","1947","Check not found","Array","33.35" 
"","0.00","1955","Check not found","Array","104.00" 
"MNC","374.40","648","checks table","Array","374.40" 
The sku listed should go with check # 1873

Comment: Try adding some output through the function I've provided to track down exactly what is happening.  It's very difficult to discern what the problem is without having all the pieces to the puzzle.  My answer should work in theory.  My only guess would be that `$skuArray` is a multi-dimesional array for some reason.  I'm expecting `$skuArray` to be something like `array('sku1','sku2','sku3');`

Comment: That is exactly what it looks like.  I will try to track down any errors I can and let you know what I find.

Comment: That's what the final output looks like.  Try doing a `var_dump` on the arrays to see what is being passed through.  Start from the top of the code and work your way down until you find why something isn't being set correctly.

Comment: I did the var_dump and posted the results.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer with a tested version of the function.  I wasn't looping through the processes array correctly.

Comment: Hi Axel, Unfortunately after all the work I put into this, the boss decided that they did not need the sku's and just wanted the order id.  Thanks for all of your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think CSV is not well suited for what you are about to do. I would use json or xml. However, you could choose a separator different from the csv sepator to represent an array, Like this:

```
foo,bar1;bar2;bar3,...
```

what would represent the following record:

```
$record = array (
   'foo',
   array ('bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3')
);
```